# Finding the PMF of number of heads resulting from second round of tosses of coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $n$ coins and each one shows heads with probability $p$, independently of each of the other coins. Each coin which shows head is tossed again. What is the probability mass function of the number of heads resulting from the second round of tosses?

My attempt is:

Define $Y$ to be the number of heads in the first round of tosses and $X$ to be the number of heads in the second round of tosses.

Then we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \sum_{y=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y) \\ = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom{y}x p^x (1-p)^{y-x} \times \binom{n}y p^y (1-p)^{n-y}.
$$
After attempting to simplify this, I couldn't get the given solution of
$$p(x) = \binom{n}x p^{2x}(1-p^2)^{n-x}.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking at this as two independent rounds consider a single process: the probability of having heads 2 times in a row, which is achieved by each coin with a probability of $p^2$. This still remains a binomial model but we have $p$ replaced by $p^2$.Thus:

$P(X=x)=\binom {n}{x}p^{2x} (1-p^{2})^{n-x}$, where X is the number of heads in the second round

Comment: Ah thats pretty simple thanks. What was wrong with my approach?

Comment: well, your sum should be from x to n, not from 0 to n. Your approach is not wrong but I don't see how I could compute that sum.

Comment: Oh yeah, because there would only be $x$ coins available for the second toss right?

Comment: exactly, you can't toss more coins than you have

Comment: Thanks I'll try to see if there's a way to compute the sum as well

Comment: Actually could I confirm that the approach is correct? Since when I equate the two expressions (the one from OP with the solution), one side is a function of $p$ yet the other side isn't a function of $p$.  
edit: actually nevermind, I was missing a factor of p^y in the sum.

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101 There is a way...

Answer (score 1):

Sum $y$ from $x$ to $n$ as $\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\mathbf 1_{x>y}=0$ (since it is impossible to toss count more after the second elimination than the first.)

Everything else is algebraic rearrangements and binomial identities.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x)
\tag 1 & = \sum_{y=x}^n \mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y)\cdot\mathsf P(Y=y)
\\ \tag 2 &= \sum_{y=x}^n\binom yx p^x(1-p)^{y-x}\cdot\binom nyp^y(1-p)^{n-y}
\\ \tag 3 &= p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\sum_{y=x}^n \binom{n}{y}\binom{y}{y-x} p^{y}
\\ \tag 4 &= p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\sum_{y=x}^n \binom{n}{n-x}\binom{n-x}{y-x} p^{y}
\\ \tag 5 &= \binom{n}{x}p^{2x}(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\sum_{y=x}^n \binom{n-x}{y-x} p^{y-x}
\\ \tag 6 &= \binom{n}{x}p^{2x}(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{n-x} \binom{n-x}{j} p^{j}
\\ \tag 7 &= \binom{n}{x}p^{2x}(1-p)^{n-x}\cdot(1+p)^{n-x}
\\ \tag 8 &= \binom{n}{x}(p^2)^{x}(1-p^2)^{n-x}
\end{align}$